# dockerhub automated build from single repo with single dockerfile building multiple images

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerhub

I have a single git repository on github with:

- a Dockerfile which builds multiple images meant to be used together. (a maven build produces a war file and sql files by downloading then from artifact repositories; a multi-stage build then creates a slim tomcat image with the war and a slim mysql image with the sql data preloaded).
- a docker-compose.yml file that uses the "target" instruction to build and run containers on the images from the multi-stage build.

This works well during development. But it forces users to build images on their computer. I want the users to be able to only download images. The setup should also be using dockerhub's automated build to keep images up to date.

How can I set it up to achieve this ? What command(s) or file(s) do I give the users to allow them to download images and run containers ? If it is not possible, what can I do to make it possible (split the repo? copypaste the dockerfile? publish intermediate images to dockerhub and ensure a correct build order ? Don't use dockerhub's automated build ?)

Comment: If it's public (and I'm guessing it is if you're looking at dockerhub) it would be cool if you could link to the Dockerfile

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml were at https://github.com/lutece-platform/lutece-demo-site-appointment/tree/ac932e9776d7dd925f6d1f0749ee8a3fe0adb7a4

Comment: Thanks for sharing. From a quick glance I imagine you could split the Dockerfile up into one file for the web app and one for the db if you wanted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use [dockerhub's automated builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) you would need to build one image per Dockerfile and have one [Dockerfile per repo](https://forums.docker.com/t/automated-build-on-docker-hub-is-there-a-way-to-specify-a-dockerfile/1078/4). The image name comes from the source repository name (with the github org/user name as the docker image user name and the github repo name as the docker image name). Multistage builds work in automated builds but only one image is published per Dockerfile (the final image of the build).

You could build the images in your CI or even on your local machine and then push to dockerhub. You'd just need to have an account on dockerhub and be logged in to that account when you use the [`docker push` command](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/push-images/). When doing this push there doesn't have to be any mapping to GitHub repos but your image names should start with `<dockerhub_user>/` as a kind of prefix (explained at https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/repos/). It's ok if they are built under a different name as you could rename by retagging before pushing. This way you can also build the images however you like.

When you have images in dockerhub you can just refer to them in the docker-compose file using the form `image: <dockerhub_user>/<dockerhub_image_name>:<tag>`. The images will automatically be pulled when the user does `docker-compose up`.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips and links that should help your situation:

### [Automated builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/) are a convenient way to deploy your images.

This part is pretty easy. You'll need accounts with Docker Hub and Github. You can register these accounts for free.

When you create a a repository on Docker Hub you can link it to your Github repository to automate the build.

Recommendations:

- [Split your services](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#decouple-applications) into separate Dockerfiles. Ideally you should use separate repositories: Docker Compose will pull them together at the end. A division of services will also help if anyone wants to implement e.g. a cloud database backend for their deployment.
- Don't store database files inside a container. [Containers should be ephemeral](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#create-ephemeral-containers)
- For a robust design, [test your builds](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/automated-testing/).

### Docker Hub automated builds are very flexible with the use of [build hooks](https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/builds/advanced/#custom-build-phase-hooks).

This part is a little tricky because I haven't found the best documentation. It also might not be necessary if you split your Dockerfile.

I've successfully created automated builds with multiple tags and targets using a hook at `hooks/build` but after reading the documentation it looks like you should also be able to use `hooks/post_build`.

Your hook could simply build the correct layer and push the tag to Docker Hub

For your repository that should look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker build --target lutece-mysql -t lutece/mysql .
docker push lutece/mysql
```

If you end up using `hooks/build` you might need to build the final target as the last step.

Recommendations:

- If you need multiple tags for an image use a hook at `hooks/post_push` to add additional tags. That way each tag *should* link users to the same image. e.g.

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env bash

  docker tag lutece/tomcat:master lutece/tomcat:latest
  docker push lutece/tomcat:latest
  ```
- Additionally you can use build hooks to label your image with things like [build date and git commit](https://microbadger.com/labels).

### [Deployment with Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/)

Unfortunately I haven't done this part so I can't confirm how to get this to work.

With your repositories in Docker Hub and a working docker-compose.yml your clients may only need to run `docker-compose up` in the directory with your docker-compose.yml file. Docker Compose should pull in the images from Docker Hub.